# instalacion de selenium para spyder

Tags: selenium, anaconda

he intentado instalar `selenium`, uso `spyder3` de `anaconda`.

lo he instalado así:

```
conda install -c conda-forge selenium
```

tambien con `pip` desde el directorio Anaconda3

> me da error de no encontrar webdriver

pero la libreria selenium la encuentra.

sabéis que puede ser?

gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Para que selenium funcione se necesita alinear tres elementos:

1. La version de selenium (Que entiendo que ya la tienes instalada para anaconda, seguramente sea la ultima)
2. La version del navegador que tienes instalada (por ejemplo, la ultima version de Firefox)
3. El web driver de cada uno de los navegadores que utilizaras (por ejemplo la ultima version de [gecko driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases))

Y una vez que tienes estas tres cosas, en tu codigo, debes indicarle al programa donde se encuentra el webdriver que has descargado para que sepa como levantarlo.

Comment: Gracias, J. BARRIO. lo pude solventar, el problema es que tenia instalado Spyder con ANaconda2 .. y me llamaba a esa biblioteca,.. Gracias de todas formas, de verda!